# Add single sign-on into existing web app

Tags: active-directory, authentication, single-sign-on, web-applications

Apologies if this isn't the best site, I've search for an answer but can't find anything quite right.  I don't actually know the correct terminology I should be using here, so any pointers will be appreciated.

I have a web application that accessed by many different users across different organisations.  Access is provided by each user having a unique username/password which is stored in SQL (database fields are customerID, userID, username).

Some organisations are now asking if we can change this to allow "Active Directory single sign-on" so that users don't need to remember yet another set of login details.
From research I can see how this is achieved using OpenAuth and Google (etc), but I know hardly anything about AD and can't find much information on this (again I'm sure it helps when you know the terminology).

Is this request even possible to achieve, given that most users will be from different (and unrelated) organisations?  I saw on a Microsoft Build video not long ago that there is some kind of replication service for AD to allow Cloud authentication.  Is this  what I should be aiming for?

Comment: If they're separate organizations, your app will have to authenticate against *their* AD domain which may or may not be possible depending on what the web app is and how it works.

Comment: Web app is simply forms authentication at present and all user data is stored in the SQL database (no reliance on anything else). This request is purely for authentication. It will be developed based on the solution. I read an article to suggest that the new "Azure multi-tenant AD" service can prevent having to authenticate against *their* domain.  Is that true?

Comment: If it does have to authenticate against *their* domain, is this done via a URL to the domain?  What information would I need to keep regarding each organisation's domain?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_Directory_Federation_Services